# $(':input').val('0'); ==> SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firebug

I have a form with a bunch of mandatory fields. 
When test the form I've tried to create default value with 0 using `jQuery`, but an error message raised:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

Here's the code:

```
$(':input').val('0');
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What type of `input` elements are in your form? If there is a `<input type="file" />` then I think setting their `value` isn't possible. Try using a selector that doesn't capture any `input[type=file]` elements. Setting the value of other `input`s or `select`s should be fine